# Capture tree node changed event

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/api/) and would like to make some ajax calls when a node is selected. I do not want to trigger the ajax call if the same node is clicked again. The [jstree example for listening events](https://www.jstree.com/docs/events/) uses [changed.jstree](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=changed)
as below:

```
$('#jstree')
  // listen for event
  .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
//my custom code here that should trigger if a new node is selected
});
```

However this gets triggered if I click the same node twice. I couldn't find anything in the data or event object e that would tell me whether this is same as the previously selected node. Is there anything in jstree to help me figure this out? If not what is the best way to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we can use changed plugin to determine the selected and deselected nodes.It's the first plugin shown [here](https://www.jstree.com/plugins/)

Create jstree and include *changed* in the plugins array:

```
 $('#jstree').jstree(
            {
                "core": {
                    "multiple": false,
                    // so that create works
                    "check_callback": true,
                    "data": menu
                },
                "plugins": ["changed"]
            }
    );
```

If both selected and deselected arrays are empty that means the selection hasn't changed:

```
$('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
  if (!(data.changed.selected.length === 0 && data.changed.deselected.length === 0))
  {
      //This is when something is really changed.
});
```